# How to make the protubuf-net not take into account the default array values when deserializing

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I use protobuf-net version 2.3.13.

Simple code:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Data
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public bool[] Flags = new bool[3] { true, true, true };
}

var data = new Data();
// change Flags for example so:
data.Flags = new bool[3] { false, false, false };
// serialize data to file
// deserialize value from file to newData
// now newData.Flags has six bool values { true, true, true, false, false, 
// false }
// but i need { false, false, false }
```

Because as I understand it, the protobuf-net first creates an instance of the class with the default values of the array, and then adds, but does not replace, its value from the file.

Is it possible to make the protubuf-net not take into account the default array values when deserializing?

Comment: Note: seralizing bools via an array is an incredibly expensive way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that protobuf-net deserializes list (etc) data by appending data.

Solution is moving list initialization from ctor to constructor with setting attribute SkipConstructor=true.

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)]
public class Data
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public bool[] Flags;

    public Data()
    {
        Falgs = new bool[3] { true, true, true }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you can also do this by telling the `[ProtoMember]` to overwrite the list rather than append (there's a bool there), but skipping the initial value will be more efficient, yes